# HIVE escaped by not working '\\'

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have a data-set in S3

`123, "some random, text", "", "", 236`

I build a external table on this dataset :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db1.myData(
    field1 bigint, 
    field2 string, 
    field3 string, 
    field4 string, 
    field5 bigint, 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LOCATION 's3n://thisMyData/';
```

**Problem/ Issue :**
 when I do 
`select * from db1.myData`

field2 is shown as

```
some random
```

I need the field to  be

```
some random, text
```

**Gotcha's :**
1. I cannot change the delimiter as there are over ~300 .csv files at this location
2. ESCAPED BY is not escaping the '\\'
3. I'm using HIVE 0.13 so there I cannot use CSV SerDe and neither i'm allowed to import new jars to cluster (its a complicated process to add a new jar as I have to go through Director level approvals)

Question:

- Is there a workaround for making 'ESCAPED BY' come alive ?!
- Any other workarounds for this ??

All suggestions are welcome !!

***N.B :*** THis is not a repeat question. If you think its a repeat, please guide me to right page and I will take this off of this portal :)

Comment: did you tried '\054' ?   http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_create_table.html

Comment: Note: The CREATE TABLE clauses FIELDS TERMINATED BY, ESCAPED BY, and LINES TERMINATED BY have special rules for the string literal used for their argument, because they all require a single character. You can use a regular character surrounded by single or double quotation marks, an octal sequence such as '\054' (representing a comma), or an integer in the range -127..128 (without quotation marks or backslash), which is interpreted as a single-byte ASCII character ...

Comment: Thanks for your tip @sb0709.. I tried `FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '\054' 
 ESCAPED BY '#' ` and `FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '\054' 
 ESCAPED BY '\\' ` but neither of them worked. I'm dropping the table before recreating them. Another information I wish add here.. my metastore is S3. Please let me know if I'm missing something here

Comment: I would also like to add that in `some random, text` there is a single space between , and text `some random, _space_ text`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, sharing what you found would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use: `ESCAPED BY '\134'` which translates to: `ESCAPED BY '\'`.

Additionally, because I was calling the Athena create table statement by passing in the statement from a JSON file I had to add an extra `\` to mask the original `\` in JSON.  So my final statement within the JSON file looked like this: `ESCAPED BY '\\134'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hive 0.14, you can use CSV Serde like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a string, b string, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Refer below link for details:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But as mentioned in Gotcha-3 I'm using Hive 0.13